# UnauthorizedAccessException when creating directory but only when impersonating myself

Tags: c#, impersonation, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I'm currently running into an odd little problem in an installation wizard. On one single test VM--all the others are fine--I cannot create subdirectories in a directory I created. On the first screen I select an install location and, if it doesn't exist, create it:

`c:\Program Files\Foo`

Then a couple screens later, I get user credentials for the software to use and, to make sure they have the appropriate permissions, use them via impersonation to create subdirectories under Foo, say Bar and Baz. The impersonation I'm using is based on [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306158).

The thing is, if I'm logged in as myself, that first directory is created just fine. But if I put my EXACT SAME CREDENTIALS into that later screen, it fails to create those subdirs. Despite the fact that it's the same creds that the program itself are currently running under.

Also, as I said, this works literally everywhere else except this one machine. So it doesn't make any sense. All we can figure is something broken about the impersonation system. That's all we can figure. But you'd think it would show up elsewhere. If it was something with the VM, then how did we create the Foo directory in the first place?

Anyway, any suggestions would be most welcome. This is really nutso.

EDIT: I have verified my account is local Admin on the VM. Nothing helpful in the Event viewer. Also, fixed link to MS impersonator code.

Comment: Is your user account part of the  local administrator group on the VM that is not working?

Comment: Check the event logs for the exact error message. Could be in security, system, or application.

Comment: @toadflakz, yes it is.@redwards, there's nothing of note in the event logs, already checked. We trap the error in our log, and here's what we're getting:

Comment: 2015-09-11T10:56:28.0838840-05:00 - UnauthorizedAccessException thrown while creating directory 'C:\Program Files\Foo\Bar': Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\Foo\Bar' is denied.
Stack:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost)

Comment: What user/group permissions are set on `Foo` folder? While you may have permission to create folders in `C:\Program Files`, if you incorrectly set the permissions on `Foo`, you may not be allowed to create the folder `Bar` as most restrictive permissions apply.